# Cakephp using an array variable in a find operation

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, find

I am creating a shortlist which is stored in a cake Session variable

```
$this->Session->read('Item.shorlist');
```

This contains a list of comma separated IDs eg. 1,2,3,4,5

```
$shortlist =  $this->Session->read('Item.shorlist');
```

I would like to perform a find operation using the comma separated IDs in this variable in the find conditions eg:

```
$shortlist = $this->Item->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Item.id' => array($shortlist))));
```

However, this only returns 1 set of data.
If I manually put in an array eg:

```
$shortlist = $this->Item->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Item.id' => array(1,2,3,4,5))));
```

I get all 5 records returned.

Any ideas how to get around this without performing multiple finds on each id? If I look at the SQL dump I can see WHERE `Item`.`id` = ('1,2,3,4,5') using the $shortlist variable whereas if I input it manually as comma delimited integers eg: WHERE `Item`.`id` IN (1, 2, 3, 4) then the sql query works as I would like it to.
So I guess my question is how to convert a comma delimited string to comma separated integers within a variable so that the SQL does not throw an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you retrieve the session value by using this line `$shortlist =  $this->Session->read('Item.shorlist');`  will be a string, please make sure it be an array.

Use explode `$short_list_array = explode(',', $shortlist);` function to convert it into array and use

`$shortlist = $this->Item->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Item.id' => $short_list_array)));`

Comment: Thanks, I was actually exploding the string and trimming it but for some reason after combining your and @Anh-Pham answers it seems to work as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
$shortlist = array_map('trim', explode(',',$shortlist));
```

Comment: Thanks, I was actually exploding the string and trimming it but for some reason after combining your and @Vins answers it seems to work as expected and hoped. Thanks!